# Jquery unbind dialog close not work

Tags: jquery, events, dialog

I have a sequence of the dialog window and in the last dialog i'm trying make this for remove event "close" the jquery dialog this mode:

```
$("#cond").dialog({
    width:'400',
    height:'100',
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    resizable: true,
    close: function(event, ui) { 
        f();
    }
});
function f(){
    $("#cond").unbind("dialogclose");
    loadsTab('tabsCond',0);

}
```

Well, this not work, because when i call first dialog the f() is called too.
What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unbind the event i found out it's better to cancel it like this:

```
    $("#cond").dialog('option', 'close', null)
```

Look at this test fiddle (press open to open the dialog: the first time you close it alerts hi, the other times nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/jHXLJ/